# Return all values from a PHP array for a given key

Tags: php

I want to return all the values in an array for a given key. For example, if the key I select is "a" I want 'redpinkmaroon' to be returned. Currently I just get 'maroon' which is the final element.

```
$newarray = array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","a"=>"pink","a"=>"maroon");

foreach($newarray as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === "a") { echo $value; }
}
```

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: That's because there is only 1 `a` key.  Keys are unique so the following one overwrites the previous one. `print_r($newarray);`

Comment: See example 2 for overwriting keys. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Might want to revisit your other questions and accept answers or people will stop helping you.

Comment: This doesn't seem a wordpress question, please remove that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making a 2d array so something like

```
$newarray = [
   "a" => ['red','pink','maroon'],
   "b" => ['green'],
   "c" => ['blue']
];
```

Then you can access the values like this:

```
$newarray['a']
```

Which will return an array containing red pink and maroon

Comment: Thanks Jake. Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

That's because there is only one `a` key.  Keys are unique so the following one overwrites the previous one. From [PHP: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

Try `print_r($newarray);` to see.

You can define a multi-dimensional array with a sub-array under the key `a`:

```
$newarray = array("a"=>array("red","pink","maroon"),"b"=>"green","c"=>"blue");
```

Then just loop the `a` key:

```
foreach($newarray['a'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$newarray = array("a"=>array("red","pink","maroon"),"b"=>"green","c"=>"blue");

    foreach($newarray as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === "a") {
            foreach ($value as $color) {
                echo $color;
             }  
        }
    }
```